# How can use LibXL framework with FBSDK?

Tags: objective-c

In my project FBLogInKit is already in their. It's working fine. But When I am adding a LibXL Framework give a error that"The FBLogInKit is missing".
Please Help Me!

Comment: Use latest Facebook SDK and try..

Comment: I am already using latest Facebook SDK.